# Common method for adding outgoing emails to a webapp?

Tags: web-applications, email

Is there any preferred or recommended method for adding outgoing email support to a web app? I need it for the usual: user registration confirmation, notifications etc.

I've had some luck with installing postfix side by side with the webserver, but it doesn't seem to be very reliable. One of the clients wasn't able to receive emails due to their server blocking emails from my server for some unknown reason until they white-listed me manually (perhaps because I faked the sender address domain to be the same as the client's).

Is there a reliable fool proof method for doing this all too common task?

I would prefer not to go to a third party service.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/

Comment: That seems like a decent checklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reliable fool proof method for doing this all too common task?

No. Sending outgoing email is deceptively simple from a technical standpoint. You find quickly that the actual practice of it is frustrating and prone to issues like server reputation, greylisting, feedback loops, blacklists, etc. Letting a third-party handle it - some examples include Amazon SES, Mandrill, Sendgrid, Postmark - is generally the best way to do things.

Comment: For registration confirmations?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question describes deliverability issues, so I'm taking it as needing help with configuring outgoing email, not coding.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks for those third party recommendations. Can you suggest a particular one and why you prefer it?

Comment: @Ramin I use Mandrill personally and am happy there. They're likely all pretty comparable.

Comment: Yes, but why would you enlist the help of an outside service to send a single confirmation email?  Aren't outside services intended for sending spam... er, bulk email?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Mandrill's stated use case is transactional email, actually. I'm quite happy with 12k free emails a month that also allows me not to have to worry about feedback loops, reputation of my IP block, bounce handling, setting up a DKIM milter, etc.

Comment: *[shrug]* What use are emails at all if you can't even send individual ones in response to legitimate business requests?